# Adding a UIViewController subclass in Xcode 4.3

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, xcode4, uiviewcontroller

I recently upgraded to Xcode 4.3 from 4.2 and it seems they have gotten rid of the New File option to add a UIViewController subclass.  I used to be able to do the following:

File => New File... => Cocoa Touch => UIViewController subclass.

but now the options for new file seem to have changed and I cannot find this option.  Can somehow point me in the right direction?

Thank you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Under Xcode 7 the feature is a little different:

File => New => File… => iOS (Source) => **Cocoa Touch Class** => **choose "subclass of"** UIViewController.

**Edit:** Updated for Xcode 7.3

Answer (score 0):

Use `File->New->Objective-C Class`, select `UIViewController` as class.